# how to remove comma if string having comma at end

Tags: java, string

I want to remove comma at end if string ends with comma

For example

> String names = "A,B,C,"

i need to remove last comma if string ends with ","

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You could try a regular expression:

```
names = names.replaceAll(",$", "");
```

Or a simple substring:

```
if (names.endsWith(",")) {
  names = names.substring(0, names.length() - 1);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how the regEx thing works here ?

Comment: Using $ in regular expression doesn't remove commas but works just using ","

Comment: @amit Tumkur $ indicates end of string so it will remove comma only at end.

Comment: @AmitTumkur The question asked specifically about removing a comma at the end of a string which is why the regexp had a `$` to anchor the match at the end of the string.  If you want to remove all commas from a string then obviously you don't need the `$`

Answer (score 19):

```
if (names.endsWith(",")) {
    names = names.substring(0, names.length()-1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int last = names.length() - 1;
if (last > 0 && names.charAt(last) == ',') {
    names = names.substring(0, last);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel:

```
StringUtils.stripEnd(names, ",");
```

Comment: This will not work if you just want 1 comma out and there are more, e.g. `s,th,,`

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (...) {
    ....
}

int lastSeparator = stringBuilder.lastIndexOf("\n");

if (lastSeparator != -1) {
    stringBuilder.delete(lastSeparator, lastSeparator + 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using 'Java 8'

```
private static void appendNamesWithComma() {
    List<String> namesList = Arrays.asList("test1", "tester2", "testers3", "t4");
    System.out.println(namesList.stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));

}
```